# duplicates in mysql full join

Tags: mysql, outer-join

I have two tables and I want to put them together and dont want to get the same id, instead I want to have the rows with the value and not with the null values - if there is an id with values.

This is my query

```
(SELECT users_antworten.user,
        users_antworten.antwort,
        profilfragen.id,
        profilfragen.frage,
        profilfragen.status,
        profilfragen.aktiviert
    FROM users_antworten

    right JOIN profilfragen ON users_antworten.frage = NULL
    WHERE profilfragen.aktiviert = 1 
    group by profilfragen.id
)
UNION               
(SELECT users_antworten.user,
        users_antworten.antwort,
        profilfragen.id,
        profilfragen.frage,
        profilfragen.status,
        profilfragen.aktiviert
 FROM users_antworten
 LEFT JOIN profilfragen ON users_antworten.frage  = profilfragen.id
 WHERE   profilfragen.aktiviert = 1 AND users_antworten.user = 6 
 group by profilfragen.id
)
```

Thank you!
[image: table one]
[image: result]

[image: table two]

Comment: That sounds like you want an `INNER JOIN`, not `FULL JOIN`

Comment: No i dont think so.
I want to have this result:

6 .      1       bla bla 1 .      1 .  frage 1
null  null .   null                 2 .  frage 2
6 .      3 .     antowrt 3 .     3 .   frage 3

and so on

Comment: Can you add your tables as text (which we can use) as opposed to images (which we can't use)

Comment: Don't use group by if you are not using aggregate functions -DISTINCT may be appropriate

Comment: Tried distinct but not working

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input (as initialization code) with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. For errors that includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, which includes constraints & indexes & tabular initialization. PS Clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 0):

Finally after hours :-) I've got it:

```
            (select null as user,
                null as antwort,
                p.id,
                p.frage,
                p.status,
                p.aktiviert
                FROM profilfragen p


                WHERE not exists
                ( SELECT null
                    FROM users_antworten u
                    WHERE u.frage = p.id AND u.user=6
                )
            )

            UNION

            (SELECT u.user,
                u.antwort,
                p.id,
                p.frage,
                p.status,
                p.aktiviert
                FROM users_antworten u left join profilfragen p on p.id = u.frage  WHERE u.user= :id
            )
```